# Razorpad examples and tutorials

Tags: layout, razor, viewbag

Can some one point me to some good tutorials on using Razorpad(http://docs.razorpad.net/index.html)? How to specify a _layout.cshtml, @model, helpers such as `@Url.Content`, `@RenderBody()`, `@ViewBag`, `@Layout` etc all are throwing errors.

The documentation is very poor.

Thanks in advance.